# VAT Refund after returning home

Tags: tax-refunds, vat

I recently bought graphic cards from Estonia and got my Tax Free Form stamped from custom before leaving but since I couldn't find the office and clock was ticking for my flight, I had to leave EU without proceeding any further. Now I got the form and the bill with me, and I'm sitting at home. How to get the money back from this state?
Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Is the tax free form issued by Global Blue or a different company?

Comment: It's Global Blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tax free form was issued by Global Blue, then [this page of their site](https://www.globalblue.com/tax-free-shopping/how-to-shop-tax-free) says:

> Completed Tax Free Forms which have been stamped by Customs can be sent to:
>
> Standard and registered mail:
> Global Blue P.O.BOX 363  810 00 Bratislava  Slovakia, Europe
>
> For courier:
> Global Blue, Prievozska 4D/Block E,  821 09 Bratislava,  Slovakia,  Europe
>
> Use the Global Blue prepaid envelope provided by the shop where you made your tax free purchase. Alternatively, you may use your own envelope but you will need to pay for postage.
>
> In case you obtained Downtown Cash Refund (Fast Refund/VAT OFF), Global Blue must receive your completed  Tax Free Form and reciepts within 21 days of the purchase to avoid charges to your credit card, plus a penalty. For refunds with China UnionPay, the Form must be received within 15 days.
>
> Before sending the documents, we advise that you make a copy of them, and write down Tax Free Form number (DOC ID) of each Form for your reference.

Comment: Well, sorry for late update but, in my homeland, Global Blue said, you can post your papers to us and we will take care of it for you. I'll update as things advance here but still I guess I'll mark your answer. Thanks a lot.